# How API works in RSA Archer ?

Tags: datafeed, archer, rsa-archer-grc

I am looking for API in Archer. Totally I am unaware of API. Where we will write API code and how to integrate with Archer platform .

Most important what we can achieve using API in Archer ?

Answer (score 5):

Archer supports two APIs.  One is SOAP and one is RESTful.  Using these APIs a developer can accomplish many of the same types of actions that can be done through the Archer UI including: user management, content save, record search, attachment upload and download, and even triggering a data feed to execute.

The API programming guides are available on the [RSA Archer community](https://community.rsa.com/community/products/archer-grc/archer-55).

You can host the integration code wherever you like, provided it has access to your archer instance.  If your Archer instance is SaaS hosted, your integration code cannot live on your Archer web or services server and will have to be hosted somewhere else.  If your Archer instance is self-hosted (on-prem) you can put your integration code on the Archer web or services server, or another server of your choice.

Archer is written in C#.NET, but the API's can be consumed from any language that can issue an HTTP Request.

Comment: Recently Javascript transporter has been introduced, could you please elaborate on this: I created a javascript file with one command (console.log("test");) I want that script to be executed However when I run it comes back faulted.

Comment: The JavaScript transporter is a recent addition to the Data Feed Manager. It allows an Archer administrator to create a data feed that gets its source data from the output of a JavaScript. For more information on this exciting new feature, check out [this recent blog post](https://community.rsa.com/community/products/archer-grc/archer-customer-partner-community/blog/2018/05/02/javascript-transporter-with-rsa-archer-64) by Archer expert  Scott Hagemeyer.