# How to consume the RSA Archer REST API to fetch Report?

Tags: rest, postman, archer

Unable to retrieve ANY data when I try to fetch simple content from Archer via REST API calls through Postman or Mule.
1. Is URL below correct? What am I missing?
2. How to get Reports via Archer REST API i.e what API resource to use.

Have seen the Archer REST documentation but do not find it clear enough.

Have tried GET & POST, with Authorization configured, through Postman:
https://hostname/platformapi/core/security/login https://hostname/platformapi/core/content/123
https://hostname/RsaArcher/platformapi/core/content/123

I get 'Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.' error although I am told to have access.

Please suggest proper API call/path to be used and if any specific settings is to be made to retrieve data?
Archer version: 6.5

Note: Through POSTMAN and Mule, I have successfully consumed REST API from other secured applications. Struggling with Archer.
Thank you.

Comment: This question is not Mule specific. It is related to how to use the Archer REST API.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for Archer REST API was mentioned in a previous answer and seems to require a login into their site: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38511131/721855

This KB article shows examples on how to use the API from Powershell: https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-45643. It should be easy to adapt to Postman, Mule or whatever other language/tools.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I had checked these references and documentation earlier but I still could not get results in Postman. These posts are couple years old and so I thought any recent experience would help.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue. The company had anonymous authentication disabled on the api directory. The user account running postman must have access to the api directory. If you are still getting a 401, see if you anonymous access can be enabled to rule out other non-access related issues. If you are able to generate a security token when calling core/security/login when anonymous authentication is enabled, then you know the issue is that your account did not have access to the api directory. If you are not able to make the request successfully with anonymous authentication enabled, then you know the issue is likely with the way you've structured your REST call. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Authentication to any Archer API is two step process. First you have to call an authentication resource or method. That will return a session token. You must then add that token to the request headers for subsequent requests. Your header would look something like this:

Authorization: Archer session-id=439C730FF83F68EFDC017ED705D9908E

Without this header, you'll get a 401 for any request other than an authentication request.